# How to view script of executed dynamic TSQL query

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, ssms

I created a stored procedure using dynamic SQL and a cursor a while ago. For upkeeping and adjusting purposes, I'm starting to think that standard SQL would be better than having to adjust the cursor. However, to assess this option, I really don't want to go through rewritting all this logic.

Is there a way to see what queries my cursor creates? I realize there is SQL Profiler (which I used very little), however, after a quick search, I saw that it'll simply display "exec my_stored_procedure" instead of showing the entire script.

Are there any ideas?

My SQL Server version: Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU22) (KB4577467) - 14.0.3356.20 (X64)   Aug 20 2020 22:33:27   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2019 Standard 10.0  (Build 17763: ) (Hypervisor)

Thank you

Comment: If its a one time thing you could add a print to the SP to get what is output for what your dynamic SQL does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your dynamic SQL is built in a variable before being executed, you could just use a `PRINT` statement to see what the queries are, like `PRINT @SQL`.  Then it would show in your Messages window in SSMS.

Comment: Awesome thank you! Initially, I forgot to mention that the dynamic TSQL has a cursor in it, and I thought that it would be problematic. However, nope. Just tested your suggestion and it works!

Comment: I'll approve your answer as soon as StackOverflow allows me... tells me to wait 4 minutes

Comment: Much appreciated.  Glad it worked for you.